# how to have another event on second click of button (not double click)

Tags: ajax, jquery, click

This seems like a really easy question, but I can't seem to find the answer.

Now that `toggle()` is deprecated for click events, how would I have say a button add DOM elements on the first click, then remove those same DOM elements on the second click?

Also.... how do I remove contents from a div I have inserted content into (using `load()`) without removing the div itself? Using `remove()` removes the div.

Comment: "Now that toggle() is deprecated", I don't think it's deprecated http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: For mouse events....  http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: @JustinBicknell  wrong toggle

Comment: Gotcha - but why not use the regular toggle()?

Comment: I tried using regular toggle, actually. Before I could even click the button my dom elements would appear then disappear. The toggle you linked is for animation.

Comment: That's not quite right - "With no parameters, the .toggle() method simply toggles the visibility of elements:" straight from the jQuery docs... http://jsfiddle.net/5w95D/

Comment: @JustinBicknell that's not what OP wants to do

Comment: @JustinBicknell Ah, I see what you're getting at. That's a good demo for toggling visibility of an element actually. I think that doesn't work in my case because I'm inserting and removing elements, instead of simply showing/hiding them.

Comment: okay wasn't sure if that would be sufficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `empty()` to clear an elements inner html

As for the toggle issue, you can toggle a class on the element and test for that class:

```
$('#myDiv').on('click', function(){
   if(! $(this).hasClass('clicked') ){
      /* code for first click*/
   }else{
      /* code for second click*/
   }
   $(this).toggleClass('clicked')
})
```

Comment: correct... I used `not` so first set of code would be first click

Answer (score 0):

your click would first check for the presence of the dom elements that get added (use an id perhaps).

```
if $('div#id of the stuff you add') 
    $('element exists...').remove();
else
    $('div#id of where you want to add stuff').add( new code );
```

You can clear a div contents with:

```
divSomeDiv.html("");

or 

divSomeDiv.empty();
```

Comment: hmm.. so to check I'm guessing I would use something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538961/jquery-check-if-dom-element-already-exists