# JQuery Check If HTML Table Headers Already Exist

Tags: jquery, html

So what I'm trying to do is *either* prevent table headers `<th>Username</th>` etc... from being rewritten to the page once they are already there, or clear what exists in the `results` element and rewrite it. Nothing I try seems to be working. I'm trying to check `.length == 0` or `< 1` or `< 2`, trying to check `.get(0)`, `.text("")`, nothing seems to work from [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538961/jquery-check-if-dom-element-already-exists). Either it just keeps rewriting the headers or it doesn't write them at all.  I want it to either append only the results rather than the headers or preferably **clear the results and rewrite everything anew when I click the button each time**. The problem is that when I click the button each time, I think the length starts over at 0 or the entryIndex is back to 0.

```
    <div>
    <h4>Results</h4>
    <table class="table" style="white-space: nowrap" id="results">

    </table>
</div>
<script>
    $('#lookup').click(function (event) {
        strUser = $('#userid').val();
        lookfor = JSON.parse('{ "username":"' + strUser + '" }');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/FindUser",
            data: lookfor,
        }).done(function (data) {
            var html = ""
            if ($('#results').length < 2) {
                html += "<tr>"
                html += "<th>Username</th>"
                html += "<th>Server</th>"
                html += "<th>App</th>"
                html += "</tr>"
            }


            var err = ""

            $.each(data, function (entryIndex, entry) {
                if (entry.ErrorMessage) {
                    err = "<tr>"
                    err += "<td>" + entry.ErrorMessage + "</td>"
                    err += "</tr>"
                } else {
                    html += "<tr>"
                    html += "<td>" + entry.UserId + "</td>"
                    html += "<td>" + entry.ServerName + "</td>"
                    html += "<td>" + entry.AppName + "</td>"
                    html += "</tr>"  
                }         
            });
            if (err.length > 0) {
                $('#results').append($(err));
            } else {
                $('#results').append($(html));
            }


        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It looks like a concurrency issue. You need to have the header check inside your each function.

Comment: Tried that a few times, changes nothing about the problem. Same issue regardless if I put it in the loop or not.  I'm not even sure what the length of the results element is to begin with.

Comment: Have you console logged the length to see what result is returned?

Comment: I actually tried to write the length to the page itself but I didn't think of writing it to the console instead. It says the length is 1, but it says that every single time regardless of what's been appended.

Comment: That’s because the element exists on the page exactly once. See my answer below on index checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <div>
    <h4>Results</h4>
    <table class="table" style="white-space: nowrap" id="results">

    </table>
</div>
<script>
    $('#lookup').click(function (event) {
        strUser = $('#userid').val();
        lookfor = JSON.parse('{ "username":"' + strUser + '" }');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/FindUser",
            data: lookfor,
        }).done(function (data) {
            var html = "";
            var err = "";

            $.each(data, function (entryIndex, entry) {
                if (entryIndex == 0) {
                    html += "<tr>"
                    html += "<th>Username</th>"
                    html += "<th>Server</th>"
                    html += "<th>App</th>"
                    html += "</tr>"
                }
                if (entry.ErrorMessage) {
                    err = "<tr>"
                    err += "<td>" + entry.ErrorMessage + "</td>"
                    err += "</tr>"
                } else {
                    html += "<tr>"
                    html += "<td>" + entry.UserId + "</td>"
                    html += "<td>" + entry.ServerName + "</td>"
                    html += "<td>" + entry.AppName + "</td>"
                    html += "</tr>"  
                }         
            });
            if (err.length > 0) {
                $('#results').append($(err));
            } else {
                $('#results').append($(html));
            }


        });
    });
</script>
```

You have the indexing of your array using the each function, so you know the first item in your array. You can use the index to conditionally add your header.

Comment: I think you're onto something here but this exact solution doesn't seem to be working. It's still writing the headers every time. I think the confusion is that this is happening in the loop, but no it's happening when I click the button again. entryIndex is 0 each time I click the button. It would actually be better if I could just clear the contents and start over. The reason there's an each loop is that sometimes there's more than one result when you click the button.

Comment: Ok. You can empty it each click. Just put $('#results').html(""); on the first line of your click event.