# Wordpress - enqueue script only if specific class is on page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

What would be the most appropriate solution to enqueue a script in WordPress only when a class of .google-map is detected on that page?

In my main.js I can detect the item on the page and do something, but I am not so sure you can use the enqueue function in a JS file.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if (document.getElementsByClassName('.google-map')) {
    alert(true);
  }
});
```

The above is just attempt #1. Please feel free to provide any other solutions, using functions or anything else. I am simply not too sure what is possible that's why I don't have more examples.

Comment: Your solution above is the right track. Why not just make functions that are called when the class name is detected. No need to use WP to execute the plan.

Comment: @omukiguy Yeah I thought using a function would be better but it's a matter of calling a function when a class is detected I don't know how to do. I presumed this would have to be in a PHP file and not in JS and therefore can't use getElementsByClassName.

Comment: This is how I see what you have explained. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538961/jquery-check-if-dom-element-already-exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordinarily add the file google.js (or whatever name you choose) to WP footer by adding the code below into your functions.php file. This will add the javascript file into WP footer the right way. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

```
function my_scriptings_scripts() {  

    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_scriptings', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/google.js', array('jquery'), '20171212', true );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scriptings_scripts' );
```

Inside your js/google.js

Using Vanilla javascript, check for the element with class name. If it exists then call the function for the action.

```
var element =  document.getElementByClassName('google-map');
  if (typeof(element) != 'undefined' && element != null)
  { 
     //call function for google actions
     google_acts_like_this();
  }

function google_acts_like_this(){
  console.log('Google will take over the world');
  alert('Google will take over the world');
}
```

OR Try wi`enter code here`th Jquery -

```
 if ($(document).find(.google-map).length > 0) 
   { 
      //If the element exist, then do something.
      google_acts_like_this();
   }

function google_acts_like_this(){
      console.log('Google will take over the world');
      alert('Google will take over the world');
    }
```

Comment: I get this part, but it's the // exists part which I don't get. How do you add a new <script> to the footer with the rest of my <scripts> with jquery.

Comment: I hope I answered your query above.

Comment: Upvoted for the alert messages