# Fire a script only of the element is present in the DOM

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a CMS and I have a lot of table initialized in this way.
I have a single script for every table, and of course the script is fired also if $('#forum_table') is not present and `KTDatatable` return to me an alert. 
I know that I can add a check on the element, but which is the cleanest way to avoid a script fire if the element doesn't exist?

```
"use strict";
// Class definition

var KTForumTable = function() {
    // Private functions

    // init initializer
    var init = function() {
        var datatable = $('#forum_table').KTDatatable();
    };

    return {
        init: function() {
            init();
        },
    };
}();

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function()  {
    KTForumTable.init();
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery - Check if DOM element already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538961/jquery-check-if-dom-element-already-exists)

Comment: I know, but I don't know js very well. I ask if there is something like "if element doesn't esist return" instead of wrapping the function inside in if...

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('selector#here').length == 0)){
  /*code on missing*/
}else{
  /* code on presetn*/
}
```